# Scala: "apply" method in companion are required to create case class instance?

Tags: scala, traits, cons

The below code defines a List type and two implementation of case classes one representing empty list and Cons to create actual list

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {
  ...
  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = {
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }
  val example = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))
}
```

is my assumption correct that the list is created by the recursive apply method above when the `val example = ...` is executed.

if that is so. the signature for creating Cons is `Cons(head, tail)` where as the signature of the apply is incompatible `variad` `def apply[A](as: A*): List[A]`, how does scala actually infers the `val example` to be `List(1, 2, 3, Nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
class Foo(s: String, i: Int)
```

in scala, it generates a class `Foo` with a constructor taking a `String` and an `Int`.

It's pretty much the same as a java class declared as

```
public class Foo {
   public Foo(String s, int i) {
       ...
   }
}
```

With case classes, the compiler provides extra-goodies such as a companion object with a default `apply` method taking the same parameters as the constructor.

So that's why you can directly call `Cons(head, tail)`, without explicitly define a constructor.

Comment: what about `val example2 = List(1,2,3)`, actually I'm trying to understand how the Cons instance is being created, since there is no constructor where I say put the head and tail together to create the Cons[Int], how does scala achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `Const` is a case class, hence it has a constructor, taking an `A` and a `List[A]`. You explicitly call it in the else branch of the `apply` method.

Comment: If you could pardon my novice I'll try to explain. As you mentioned Cons has an empty constructor since it has no body. Apply calls Cons recursively to create it's instance. But the parameter of apply and Cons constructor are different.

Comment: Nope, `Cons` has an implicit constructor taking exactly those parameters. Check my updated answer